# Can I change the content of a column in Beamer as part of animation?

Tags: beamer, animations

I'm creating a presentation, and I have 3x2 columns. You can see the code segment below:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Intro}
% First 1x2 part, first column
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{pic1} 
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item 1
            \item 2
            \item 3
        \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\vfill
% Second 1x2 part, second column
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{pic2} 
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item 1
            \item 2
            \item 3
        \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\vfill
% Third 1x2 part, third column
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{pic3} 
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item 1
            \item 2
        \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

What I want to do is that give some kind of animation. Meaning when I present when the slide opens at the beginning I want it to be empty and just the title. Then, in the next click I want the first column to be displayed, meaning the first 1x2 part. Then, in the second click, I want the second 1x2 (the second column) to be displayed, but at the same time I want the contents of the first column, first 1x2 part to be replaced with another picture. And in the last click I just want the last 1x2, meaning last column to be displayed. Any ideas how can I achieve something like this, if it is possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such simple animation, you can use `\pause`. If you need more fine control, read section `9 Creating Overlays` of the beamer user guide.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Intro}
% First 1x2 part, first column
\pause
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics<2>[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-a} 
        \includegraphics<3->[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-b} 
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item 1
            \item 2
            \item 3
        \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\vfill
\pause
% Second 1x2 part, second column
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image} 
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item 1
            \item 2
            \item 3
        \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\vfill
\pause
% Third 1x2 part, third column
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image} 
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item 1
            \item 2
        \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's doing what I want to certain extend.  In the second pause, after that when the second column is displayed, I also want the contents of the first column to  change. Basically instead of still displaying the stuff between first and second pause line, I want to display another picture at that place, let's say example-image2.

Comment: @typos See the edit. Just tell `\includegraphics` on which overlays it should be present.

Comment: Thanks, this is much closer to my needs :). One last question, can overlay be applied to a whole column? I mean for example, can I create one more column inside the first columns, and give an overlay of 3, and to the other two column an overlay of 2. So that in overlay 3, I have a column with different width than the other two column?

Comment: @typos Yes, its possible. `\only<>{}` would do that, just read "9 Creating Overlays" of the beamer user guide.

Comment: `\begin{columns}[totalwidth=\textwidth] ... \end[columns}`